# APS - Forge - Autodesk Platform Services: traslation from NWD Navisworks to STL

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I have tried with Autodesk Model Derivate the workflow to obtain a STL file from a NWd model of Navisworks.

The way that I have followed is:
from Naviswork I have exported a FBX file of the NWD model.
Then I have upload the FBX file to APL,
and finally translated it to STL.

I have two questions:

1. there is another way that I could follow? eg Can I directly translate to STL an NWD model that I have already in the APS bucket?
2. Is it possible to set parameters of translation? I have seen that the cylinders were approximated with dodecahedrons, and I would like to obtain more resolution

Thank you in advance

Comment: Happy New Year! I hate to disappoint you, but APS has not yet support for your two questions. We could log a new feature for question 1. As to question 2, I am afraid that is out of the scope of Model Derivative if the source FBX's resolution is already less. I do not either see an option when Navisworks exports FBX..